# Ajax call doesn't work from iPhone app and arduino

Tags: php, ios, ajax

I've created an Arduino project wich sends the coordinates to an URL. The URL does some ajax calls. In the browser it works fine, but when I'm trying it with the Arduino it doesn't work. So I tried to do the same thing with an iOS app, but I got the same problem. This is the code on the page that the Arduino and iOS app request.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var base_url = window.location;
var received_data = <?php echo json_encode($received_data); ?>;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gps-tracker.domain.nl/_api/handler.php',
    data: { action: 'post', device_id: received_data['device_id']},
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:"jsonp",
    jsonp:"callback",
    success: function (response){
        var error = [];
        var total = response.length;

        for (var type in response) {

            if(response[type].types == 'area'){

                var x = checkInsideCircle(response[type].longitude, response[type].latitude, received_data['longitude'], received_data['latitude'], response[type].reach / 1000); 

                if(x == false){
                    // Outside
                    error.push(true);
                }else{
                    // Inside
                    error.push(false);
                }
            }else if(response[type].types == 'route'){

                // Check route
                checkOnRoute(response[type].start_latitude, response[type].start_longitude, response[type].end_latitude, response[type].end_longitude, response[type].type, response[type]['reach'], type, function(result) {

                    error.push(result);

                    if(error.length == total){

                        if(error.indexOf(false) >= 0){

                            // Device is inside route or area
                            outside = false;
                        }else{
                            // Send data to database
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://gps-tracker.domain.nl/_api/handler.php',
                                data: { action: 'post', device_id: received_data['device_id'], longitude: received_data['longitude'], latitude: received_data['latitude']},
                                type: 'GET',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (response){
                                    console.log('good');
                                },error: function(jq,status,message) {
                                    alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },error: function(jq,status,message) {
        alert('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message);
    }
});
```

Here is the code from the handler.php file, that the ajax request requests.

```
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : false;

// Switch actions
switch($action) {
    case 'get':
        $callback ='callback';

        if(isset($_GET['callback'])){
            $callback = $_GET['callback'];
        }

        $routes = ORM::for_table('gps_tracker_route')
                ->inner_join('gps_tracker_device', array('gps_tracker_device.device_id', '=', 'gps_tracker_route.device_id'))
                ->where('gps_tracker_route.device_id', $_GET['device_id'])
                ->where('gps_tracker_device.device_id', $_GET['device_id']);

        if($routes = $routes->find_many()){
            foreach($routes as $k=>$v){
                $v = $v->as_array();

                if($v['status'] == 'on' or strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($v['start_time']) and strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime($v['end_time'])){
                    $response1[$k] = $v;
                    $response1[$k]['types'] = 'route';
                } 
            }
        }

        $area = ORM::for_table('gps_tracker_area')
            ->inner_join('gps_tracker_device', array('gps_tracker_device.device_id', '=', 'gps_tracker_area.device_id'))
            ->where('gps_tracker_area.device_id', $_GET['device_id'])
            ->where('gps_tracker_device.device_id', $_GET['device_id']);

        if($area = $area->find_many()){
            foreach($area as $k=>$v){
                $v = $v->as_array();

                if($v['status'] == 'on' or strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($v['start_time']) and strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime($v['end_time'])){
                    $response2[$k] = $v;
                    $response2[$k]['types'] = 'area';
                } 
            }
        }

        if(isset($response1) and isset($response2)){
            $response = array_merge($response1, $response2);
        }elseif(isset($response1)){
            $response = $response1;
        }else{
            $response = $response2;
        }

        if ( isset($response) ) {

            if ( is_array($response) ) {
                if (function_exists('json_encode')) {
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');

                    echo $callback.'(' . json_encode($response) . ')';
                } else {
                    include( ABSOLUTE_PATH . '/classes/json.class.php');
                    $json = new Services_JSON();
                    echo $json->encode($response);
                }
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
            exit(0);
        }else{
            exit();
        }
    break;
    case 'post':

        $_GET['timestamp'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $record = ORM::for_table('gps_tracker_device_logging')->create($_GET);
        $record->save();

        $item = ORM::for_table('gps_tracker_device_logging')
        ->where('id', $record->id);


        if($item = $item->find_one()){

            $item = $item->as_array();

            echo json_encode($item);
        }

    break;
    default:
        die('invalid call');
}
```

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**

I think it is something with Javascript. I don't know if it's possible to use javascript when a device, like Arduino, makes a http request to a server. Someone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's because you need a Web Browser that supports JavaScript. 
I don't work with Arduino, but from what I know it does not have a "real" Web Browser - it can only pull/download data but can't execute the JS part. 
For JS to work you need something to run it. That is why it works in a the browser.